# How/where to supply e.Parameter for Back navigation

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps

The template code for MainPage.xaml.cs contains this method (the body code is mine).

```
/// <summary>
/// Invoked when this page is about to be displayed in a Frame.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="e">Event data that describes how this page was reached.  The Parameter
/// property is typically used to configure the page.</param>
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
  var queryParams = e.Parameter as WhitepagesQueryParams;
}
```

Note the comment clearly indicating that e.Parameter should be used to set up the page.

When a user is looking at another app page and clicks the Back button, what/where is my opportunity to supply the value that will turn up in e.Parameter?

My first thought was this

```
protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
  e.Parameter = this.DefaultViewModel["QueryParameters"];
  base.OnNavigatedFrom(e);
}
```

but e.Parameter is read only.

There is a method

```
private void GoBack(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

}
```

which is invoked when the Back button is clicked, but it doesn't seem to perform the actual navigation and again I cannot see how to supply a value.

---

Back when I was experimenting with Silverlight, I used to maintain what was essentially a ViewModel owned by the app. This solves the problem of passing state by making it unnecessary, but if I do it that way then what is the point of e.Parameter?

It crosses my mind that this approach (state model owned by app object) also provides an opportunity to sidestep the shortcomings of the implicit serialisation which currently can only serialise simple values.

Comment: Is value of `e.Parameter` of `OnNavigatedFrom(...)` same as `OnNavigatedTo(...)`?

Comment: I don't think so, it was merely a possibility that crossed my mind. My question is essentially, "Assuming this isn't a broken design, how are we *expected* to go about passing state when navigation is performed directly by the framework in response to user interaction, rather than by our own code.